# CalendarView Error to Display Multiple Highlights

Tags: android, android-calendar

**How To Highlight Multiple Days according to Calculation**

Hi. please help me how to do this.

```
package com.tgkjer.fertilitystress;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public CalendarMain main;
    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }

        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }
        //main.Calc();
        /*String s = "";
        long l = Long.parseLong(s);
        DbFertility db = new DbFertility(getActivity());
        db.open();
        int cycle = Integer.parseInt(db.getCycle(l));
        int period = Integer.parseInt(db.getPeriod(l));
        int date1 = Integer.parseInt(db.getPeriod(l));
        db.close();*/

        int periodCycleDays = 28;
        long date1 = Long.parseLong(date);
        int bleedingDays = 3;
        int fertilePhaseStart = periodCycleDays - 20;
        int fertilePhaseEnd = periodCycleDays - 11;
        int ovulation = (fertilePhaseStart-1) + (fertilePhaseEnd - fertilePhaseStart)/2;

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (periodCycleDays == 28) {
            for(long i = date1; i <= bleedingDays; i++ )
            {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            for(int j = fertilePhaseStart; j < ovulation; j++)
            {
                int b = 6;
                if(j == b)
                {
                    iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                }else{
                    iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    private Context getActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
         */
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);

        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1), month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

    public void Calculation(){

    }
}


03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): Process: com.tgkjer.fertilitystress, PID: 1294
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2015-03-01"
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.tgkjer.fertilitystress.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:137)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-01 08:43:52.412: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

"Thats the error in my logcat can u help me to specify where's the error
in my code?"

Expected Output: i want to highlights Multiple Days According to Calculation of Period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2015-03-01"
```

this exception raises when you are parsing any String number (i.e `String stringNumber="09";` where String Number is any number in between double quote like "09") which is other than number like String number having other character  is included in number like instead of "9" or "09" if it contain  "0-9","A09","A9","   ","9a","9-1" etc. this exception will thrown
you have to avoid passing all this other character.
only number as string you can pass so you will get the number as int,long etc

```
at com.tgkjer.fertilitystress.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:137)
```

at line number 90 in `

```
com.tgkjer.fertilitystress.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:90) 
String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
```

`separatedTime` will have String number i.e. `dayString` having Date value like `"2015-03-01"` thats why you are spliting value using delimiter "-"

which you are calling at line number 117 in

```
com.tgkjer.fertilitystress.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:117) 
// create date string for comparison
 String date = dayString.get(position);
```

so date is having value as date which is "2015-03-01"

```
if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
```

the above line of code at line no.119 to 121 will not fact the date value because  `date.length() == 1`   is `false` it will not enter into the if block.

now see at line no 137 in

```
com.tgkjer.fertilitystress.CalendarAdapter.getView(CalendarAdapter.java:137)
long date1 = Long.parseLong(date);
```

here the Long.parseLong() is expecting value like String number but geting a date value as String which is "2015-03-01" so exception riases.
so use your split function on date like

```
String[] separatedyyMMdd = date.split("-");
long date1yy = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[0]);
long date1mm = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[1]);
long date1dd = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[2]);
```

it will solve your above problem

Comment: My Program now is working but it highlights all the day in a month and in a year.. can u help me with this problem.
my problem is i want to highlight the days of the result of period.
My Formula...int periodCycleDays = 28;
  //long date1 = Long.parseLong(date.trim());
     int bleedingDays = 3;
     int fertilePhaseStart = periodCycleDays - 20;
     int fertilePhaseEnd = periodCycleDays - 11;
     int ovulation = (fertilePhaseStart-1) + (fertilePhaseEnd - fertilePhaseStart)/2;

Comment: String[] separatedyyMMdd = date.split("-")      long date1yy = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[0])  long date1mm = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[1]) long date1dd = Long.parseLong(separatedyyMMdd[2]);
// show icon if period result is correct
ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
if (periodCycleDays == 28) {   for(long i = date1dd; i <= bleedingDays; i++ ){ iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
for(int j = fertilePhaseStart; j < ovulation; j++) {int b = 6;
if(j == b){iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }else{
  iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }} (Can u correct my Formula? please)

Comment: hi Rhea,the condition which you have put in the for loop to show the day and hide thier in both the conditions whether true or false its showing it....

Comment: correct me if i am wrong ok.  let take a date 01-3-15,,ok and see your condition of hiding and showing the img....so as per your logic if its perioddays==28 let assume its true....so  it will display 1,2,3 as per 1st for loop and in 2nd for loop as per your condition 8,9,10 of the calender img will be visible.....here in 2nd loop same code you have written in both the condition in if as well as in else.chk out ok

Comment: yeah your answer is correct... I'm beginner in programming and still i don't get it... can you help what is the correct to do? for example if i chose the date 01-03-15 and the bleedingday is 4,, i want to highlight the 3,4,5,6 day.. what should i do to achieve that goal?